# Distribution of a process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

A radioactive source emits particles according to a Poisson Process of rate $\lambda$. Each one is emitted in a random and independent direction. A Geiger counter is used and it detects a fraction $p$ (constant and set) of the emitted particles. What is the distribution of the number of particles detected at time $t$?

Comment: It seems that you have spent enough time in this community to understand how it is important to provide your own thoughts, contexts, background, etc. Please consider reformulating your question. You may also want to give [this posting](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/9340) a read to learn how to ask a good question.

Comment: Have you heard about a splitting Poisson process before?

Comment: I have heard of it